# How can I build, test, and publish the same files for ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, deployment, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM hosted setup using .NET 7.0 RC1.

This is what I have set up in my CI now:

```
dotnet build -c Release
dotnet test -c Release
dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o ./deploy
```

However, the publish step rebuilds the app again with different files, and some optimizations for the final deploy.

Is it possible to run my tests on that final build instead of an intermediate build?

I'm asking because I've seen faulty builds a few times (on Blazor app .NET 6.0) where most everything works but there's a tiny bug in one section of the app, and so I'd really like to be able to test against the final build to prevent that.

Comment: Do you wanna test the final published file again? Maybe you can test it in IIS.

Comment: @XinranShen Well when I want to deploy the app I would like to test the published files before actually compressing and uploading to my server. Do you have any info on how to run unit/integration tests in IIS? I don't use IIS but maybe it would point me in the right direction...

Comment: You can follow this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and deploy the published to IIS and test

Comment: @XinranShen I don't think you're understanding my question. I don't mean manual testing. I mean to run my unit tests and integration tests against the final build. I don't see how IIS helps for that.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your question, But I don't think you can do unit test against the final build. We always test it then deploy.